# select names of students, whose GPA is greater than the average GPA on course and specialty

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table "student":

```
+-----+---------+---------+------------+-------+
| id  |  name   | course  | specialty  |  gpa  |
+-----+---------+---------+------------+-------+
```

How can I select names of students, whose GPA is greater than the average GPA on their course and specialty?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please show what you have tried, so that we can better help.  Also, see this [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this should work. Here we calculate the averages per course and speciality, join back onto students and filter from there.

```
Select s.name
from students s
inner join
(Select course, speciality, avg(gpa) as avg_gpa from students
group by course, speciality) a
on a.course = s.course and a.speciality = s.speciality
where s.gpa > a.avg_gpa
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? The answer has been accepted as correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name 
FROM student s
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT course , speciality , AVG(gpa) gpa
    FROM student
    GROUP BY course , speciality
) a ON s.course = a.course AND s.speciality = a.speciality
WHERE s.gpa > a.gpa
```